# Running featherJS with iron-node

Tags: node.js, npm, feathersjs, iron-node

I wish to debug a feathersJS project with iron-node, since it's the best debugging tool I found to date. Problem is, I don't know how to run the feathersJS project using iron-node, since the normal way of running it is using npm start. Can anyone help me figure out what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple enough:

```
iron-node src/index.js
```

This will start the feathers project using iron-node